# Dynamic domain in Spring Security SAML MetadataGenerator

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

we are running a Java Web application, that is accessible to the end users via two different domains ('domain1', 'domain2').

The application uses a remote provider of SAML authentication for the user login.

We are using the Spring Security SAML library to handle the SAML communication. One of the Spring beans created in our Spring configuration is the MetadataGenerator. We have set it up so that it sets the entityBaseURL always to be 'domain1'.

```
@Bean
public MetadataGenerator metadataGenerator() {
    String entityBaseUrl = environment.getProperty("saml.entity.base.url");
    MetadataGenerator metadataGenerator = new MetadataGenerator();
    ...
    metadataGenerator.setEntityBaseURL(entityBaseUrl);
    return metadataGenerator;
}
```

This causes a problem when the user accesses our application via 'domain2' URL. The SAML request is sent to the SAML provider, but once the user logs in at the Provider, she gets redirected to 'domain1', her session is lost and the SAML response is not properly mapped to the original request (at least this is how we interpret the problem).

We can see this exception in the log:

```
    2016.11.02 15:30:24.076 [ajp-nio-8009-exec-31] DEBUG  o.s.s.s.s.HttpSessionStorage  - Message a511iei787cgc6bi2a91c4264e83c4h not found in session 2cbc5d3a-5061-410a-9518-505e8d22d5a3
    2016.11.02 15:30:24.079 [ajp-nio-8009-exec-31] DEBUG  o.s.s.s.SAMLAuthenticationProvider  - Error validating SAML message
    org.opensaml.common.SAMLException: InResponseToField of the Response doesn't correspond to sent message a511iei787cgc6bi2a91c4264e83c4h
            at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.processAuthenticationResponse(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java:139) ~[spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:1.0.2.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(SAMLAuthenticationProvider.java:87) ~[spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:1.0.2.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:167) [spring-security-core-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
...
```

Is there some way/best practise how to setup the MetadataGenerator (or some other component of the system) to avoid this problem?

TIA

Martin